# Why my Revit view are blank?

Tags: view, revit

We are working on a project using workset. Recently we start to find our views blank when we start our Revit project, we need to zoom all to see the view content. It was not like that befor a new member come to our team. The same thing start happning in other project when she started working with it. What is the possible reason to that?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely an element floating in space that is stretching your view extents. It could also be an element in a linked file, revit or cad.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I zoom all in my view so I see only my building nothing outside it. If there is something out there the view will not shown like that when zooning.